# How to make a string shift backward each letter

Tags: string, dart, unicode

I am finishing some functions in a flutter project.

```
void code_shift_backward() {
  var input_string = controller.text;
  List<String> output_list = [];

  var input_runes = input_string.runes.toList();
  for (var rune in input_runes) {
    var mutatedRune = rune--;
    output_list.add(String.fromCharCode(mutatedRune));
  }

  var output_string = output_list.join("");
  setState(() {
    text_in_tree = output_string;
  });
}
```

I give it the word `wiggle` and I expect `vhffkd` but it keeps giving `wiggle`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change:

```
var mutatedRune = rune--;
```

to:

```
var mutatedRune = --rune;
```

**Explanation:**

rune-- assigns the value of rune to mutatedRune first, then reduces the value by one. It means mutatedRune and rune has the same value.

--rune reduces the value first, then assigns.

Read about Dart [arithmetic operators](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#arithmetic-operators) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the help and info!

Comment: I'd even say `var mutatedRune = rune - 1;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by moving the `--` to the front of `rune`.. This happens because putting the -- after the variable only updates the variable after that line.

```
void code_shift_backward() {
  var input_string = controller.text;
  List<String> output_list = [];

  var input_runes = input_string.runes.toList();
  for (var rune in input_runes) {
    var mutatedRune = --rune;
    output_list.add(String.fromCharCode(mutatedRune));
  }

  var output_string = output_list.join("");
  setState(() {
    text_in_tree = output_string;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For size, maybe:

```dart
String shiftBack(String input) =>
    String.fromCharCodes([for (var c in input.runes) c - 1]);
```